# TypeError at /form Field 'roof_age' expected a number but got ('1',)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

TypeError at /form
**Field 'roof_age' expected a number but got ('1',).**

My model.py file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Details(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    roof_age = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    monthly_bill = models.IntegerField()
    HOA = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    battery = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    foundation = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    roof_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    availability = models.DateTimeField()
    bill = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%d/%m/%y/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'details'
        verbose_name_plural = 'details'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My views.py file

```
def form(requests):
    if requests.method == 'POST':
        name=requests.POST['name'], 
        roof_age=requests.POST['roof_age'], 
        email = requests.POST['email'],
        phone = requests.POST['phone'], 
        address = requests.POST['address'],
        monthly_bill = requests.POST['monthly_bill'], 
        HOA = requests.POST['HOA'], 
        battery = requests.POST['battery'], 
        foundation = requests.POST['foundation'], 
        roof_type = requests.POST['roof_type'],
        availability= requests.POST['availability'],
        bill = requests.POST['bill']

        details = Details(
            name = name, 
            roof_age = roof_age, 
            email = email,
            phone = phone, 
            address = address,
            monthly_bill = monthly_bill, 
            HOA = HOA, 
            battery = battery, 
            foundation = foundation, 
            roof_type = roof_type,
            availability= availability,
            bill = bill
        )
        
        print(name, roof_age, email, phone, address, monthly_bill, HOA,battery, foundation, roof_type, availability, bill)
        print("The data has been save to db")
        details.save()

    return render(requests, 'baskin/form.html')
```

*The print statement was giving the results in form of tuples*

Now I'm getting
**TypeError: Field 'roof_age' expected a number but got ('1',).**

How can I resovle this?

Answer (score 0):

try to add `int` in this code: `roof_age=int(requests.POST.get['roof_age'])`, maybe requests.POST get value type is string, but in your model.py roof_age is IntegerField.

Comment: I changed it and now it returning tuple and I'm getting this-
TypeError: Field 'roof_age' expected a number but got (12,)

Comment: Excuse me, can you print the roof_age and check is it expected?

Comment: The print statement in the views.py file is giving me  fields in the form of tuple--> ('Nishant',) (8,) ('nishantsagar45@gmail.com',) ('8210594714',) ('Test-1',) ('5',) ('on',) ('on',) ('on',) ('Metal',) ('2022-09-23T02:09',) Git
The data has been save to db

Comment: Can you please be more specific, where to use .get, like for all the fields??